# html: open pdf and png in the browser, not to download it

Tags: html, browser, png

The code on the html page is:

```
<a href="getReport.php?id=123">View report in a new window</a>
```

Once any user clicks on it, it becomes downloaded (it is a .png file) by his browser and he is able to view it.

How can we make it opened in a new window **instead**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: Do you mean "getReport.php?id=123" isn't rendering as a .png image (it's asking the user to download)?  Or is it displaying as an image, but you want it to display in a new, separate window?

If the former, you need to make sure the server sends the correct Content-type (e.g. "image/png").

If the latter, just do a Javascript "window.open()" (or equivalent)

========  UPDATE =======

My 1990's heritage with Javascript 1.2 is catching up with me :)  *Don't* use "window.open()" - do as Pandian says and use  if you want to implement a pop-up window.  Here are more details:

- http://javascript.info/tutorial/popup-windows

By the same token, your question is vague.  If the problem is that the file is asking you to "download" (if the image isn't appearing *anywhere*), then your PHP program isn't sending the file correctly.  At a minimum, it must set "Content-type" before it sends the binary .png data.

'Hope that helps...

Comment: If the user clicks on "getReport.php?id=123", what he sees is downloaded png.

Answer (score 3):

In anchor tag give the URL of the PDF embedded page and In the PDF Embedded page, try iFrame to display the PDF, It will work

**PDF IFrame :**

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mechanical-engineering/2-000-how-and-why-machines-work-spring-2002/tools/html.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/69/

**IMAGE IFrame :**

```
<iframe src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg">
</iframe>
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/70/

Comment: You're correct: an iframe is the 21st Century way to implement HTML pop-up Windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('getReport.php?id=123', '_blank')">View report in a new window</a>
```